# Split a split (regex) in python

Tags: python, regex, split

I do have got the below string and I am looking for a way to split it in order to consistently end up with the following output

```
'1GB 02060250396L7.067,702BE 129517720L6.633,403NL 134187650L3.824,234DE 165893440L3.111,005PL 65775644897L1.010,006DE 811506926L3.547,407AT U16235008L-830,008SE U57469158L3.001,30'
```

```
['1GB 02060250396L1.060,70',
'2BE 129517720L2.639,40',
'3NL 134187650L4.024,23',
'4DE 165893440L8.111,00',
'5PL 65775644897L3.010,00',
'6DE 811506926L3.547,40',
'7AT U16235008L-830,00',
'8SE U57469158L8.0221,30']
```

My current approach
`re.split("([0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z])", input)` however is also splitting my delimiter which gives and there is no other split possible than the one I am currently using in order to remain consistent. Is it possible to split my delimiter as well and assign a part of it "70" to the string in front and a part "2BE" to the following string?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) instead of `re.split()`.

You want to match

- a number `\d`, followed by
- two letters `[A-Z]{2}`, followed by
- a space `\s`, followed by
- a bunch of characters until you encounter a comma `[^,]+,` followed by
- two digits `\d{2}`

[Try it at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/m509qp/1)

So do:

```
input_str = '1GB 02060250396L7.067,702BE 129517720L6.633,403NL 134187650L3.824,234DE 165893440L3.111,005PL 65775644897L1.010,006DE 811506926L3.547,407AT U16235008L-830,008SE U57469158L3.001,30'

re.findall(r"\d[A-Z]{2}\s[^,]+,\d{2}", input_str)
```

Which gives

```
['1GB 02060250396L7.067,70',
 '2BE 129517720L6.633,40',
 '3NL 134187650L3.824,23',
 '4DE 165893440L3.111,00',
 '5PL 65775644897L1.010,00',
 '6DE 811506926L3.547,40',
 '7AT U16235008L-830,00',
 '8SE U57469158L3.001,30']
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to be so specific with your pattern, you could simply use the regex
`[^,]+,\d{2}` [Try it at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wHRIZM/1)

This will match as many of any character except a comma, then a single comma, then two digits.

```
re.findall(r"[^,]+,\d{2}", input_str)

# Output:
['1GB 02060250396L7.067,70',
 '2BE 129517720L6.633,40',
 '3NL 134187650L3.824,23',
 '4DE 165893440L3.111,00',
 '5PL 65775644897L1.010,00',
 '6DE 811506926L3.547,40',
 '7AT U16235008L-830,00',
 '8SE U57469158L3.001,30']
```

Answer (score 1):

*Is it possible to split my delimiter as well and assign a part of it "70" to the string in front and a part "2BE" to the following string?*

If you must use `re.split` AT ANY PRICE then you might exploit zero-length assertion for this task following way

```
import re
text = '1GB 02060250396L7.067,702BE 129517720L6.633,403NL 134187650L3.824,234DE 165893440L3.111,005PL 65775644897L1.010,006DE 811506926L3.547,407AT U16235008L-830,008SE U57469158L3.001,30'
parts = re.split(r'(?<=,[0-9][0-9])', text)
print(parts)
```

output

```
['1GB 02060250396L7.067,70', '2BE 129517720L6.633,40', '3NL 134187650L3.824,23', '4DE 165893440L3.111,00', '5PL 65775644897L1.010,00', '6DE 811506926L3.547,40', '7AT U16235008L-830,00', '8SE U57469158L3.001,30', '']
```

Explanation: This particular one is positive lookbehind, it does find zero-length substring preceded by `,` digit digit. Note that parts has superfluous empty `str` at end.

Comment: Hi Daweo, could you further elaborate on the zero-length assertion please? In the case where you got ```"1IT 02060250996L7.067,70" ``` and you're working on a regex: (\d|[A-Z])[L|T|S](\d|[-]) ... how would you use the same logic here? where 6 has to remain attached to 99, L has to be a stand alone and 7 has to be attached to whatever comes after it (in this case a point (.) but could also be another number) ?